# node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/events.d.ts:106:43 - error TS2370: e node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:6:76 - error TS2792

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Estou tentando rodar um compilador, mas o mesmo acusa meus códigos do node.js de estarem incorretos

```
node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/events.d.ts:106:43 - error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.

106                 T[K] extends unknown[] ? (...args: T[K]) => void : never
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:6:76 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

6 type _Request = typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any } ? {} : import("undici-types").Request;
                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:7:77 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

7 type _Response = typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any } ? {} : import("undici-types").Response;
                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:8:77 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

8 type _FormData = typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any } ? {} : import("undici-types").FormData;
                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:9:76 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

9 type _Headers = typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any } ? {} : import("undici-types").Headers;
                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:11:14 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

11     : import("undici-types").RequestInit;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:13:14 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

13     : import("undici-types").ResponseInit;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:380:25 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

380         : typeof import("undici-types").Request;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:389:25 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

389         : typeof import("undici-types").Response;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:396:25 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

396         : typeof import("undici-types").FormData;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.d.ts:403:25 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'undici-types'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

403         : typeof import("undici-types").Headers;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 11 errors.
```

Linhas do código com seu respectivo problema apresentado:

```
K extends keyof T ? (
        T[K] extends unknown[] ? (...args: T[K]) => void : never

type _Request = typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any } ? {} : import("undici-types").Request;
type _Response = typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any } ? {} : import("undici-types").Response;
type _FormData = typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any } ? {} : import("undici-types").FormData;
type _Headers = typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any } ? {} : import("undici-types").Headers;

: typeof import("undici-types").Headers;
```

Alguem já teve este tipo de problema, ou sabe como corrigir com "npm install" para corrigir o lance de ele estar já com pacote quebrado

Comment: Você apenas colocou o código com todos os erros e jogou, você não deu contexto para que possamos te ajudar, leia antes este post para aprender a fazer uma pergunta boa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example